# Performing different actions on same button click during Runtime (Similar to twitter Follow/UnFollow)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have the following program structure:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

       ...

       ...


       if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];

            ...

            ...


            if(condition)
                {   
                    do something;
                }

            else
                {

                    if(condition)
                         {  
                            unFollowButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                            unFollowButton.frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 120, 30);

                            unFollowButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                            unFollowButton.tag = indexPath.row;
                            unFollowButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                            [unFollowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                            NSLog(@"fCheckRowCheck Value in if Condition %@",fCheckRowCheck);
                            [unFollowButton setTitle:@"UnFollow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [cell.contentView addSubview:unFollowButton];
                            buttonValue = 0;
                            NSLog(@"buttonValue %d", buttonValue);
                        }

                    else 
                        {

                            followButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                            followButton.frame = CGRectMake(180, 10, 120, 30);
                            followButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                            followButton.tag = indexPath.row;
                            followButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                            [followButton setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            [followButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                            [cell.contentView addSubview:followButton];
                            buttonValue = 1;
                            NSLog(@"buttonValue %d", buttonValue);
                        }   
                }
        }


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.infos objectAtIndex:row];
    return cell;

}




- (IBAction)buttonClicked2:(UIButton *)sender
    {
       NSLog(@"BUTTON_CLICKED");

       NSIndexPath *indexPath = [folksFolksTable indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell*)  [[sender superview]superview]];
       NSLog(@"[sender tag] is %d", [sender tag]);

       ....

       ....

       ....

       //Set up URLConnection tp send information on button click
       NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kUnFollowURL];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kId, [user objectForKey:@"id"] ]];
    [postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kfId, [fId objectForKey:@"fID"] ]];

    [postString setString: [postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSLog(@"post string = %@", postString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    followConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
    NSLog(@"postconnection: %@", followConnection);

    //Get Response from server

    NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: postString ]];    
    NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"serverOutput = %@", serverOutput);

    //Change the button lable from unfollow to follow

    [sender setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 




     if([sender tag]==indexPath.row)
        {
            textField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:[sender tag]];
            NSLog(@"txtF is %@",textField);        
            textField.hidden=NO;
        }


}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked1:(UIButton *)sender
      {

          similar to buttonClicked 2

      }
```

What I need is that the button should perform the corresponding action as well after the label has changed during runtime.

For example, I am following someone [ button label unfollow], if i click on the button [ button label becomes follow at that instant ( which is happening perfectly OK ). Now when i click the same button again with "follow" label, it is throwing exception.

How to go about it. Please help me figure it out ?

Comment: Keep a break-point and see what&where the exception is coming exactly also do the connection part at a different place and call the method in your button..is ARC enabled?

Comment: I have added this just after i am changin the button textsender addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked2::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: and i am getting following exception: 2012-05-17 19:14:16.704 fbee[682:10103] -[folksFolks buttonClicked2::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8145f10
2012-05-17 19:14:16.705 fbee[682:10103] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[folksFolks buttonClicked2::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8145f10'

Comment: @roronoazorro no this file is not arc enabled

Comment: When u setTitle of the buton try casting it to UIButton ..(UIButton *)sender setTitle...

Comment: I have an idea but i dont know how to do it, after pressing the button in its initial state say follow, i can call the webservice for follow and after that i can reload the tableview . But i dont know how to reload the tabelview automatically.

Comment: hey, just solved it... check out the edit part of the question

Comment: @roronoazorro check out the edit part of the question and hopefully you can give me some credit as well...

Comment: @TheSaad check out the edit part of the question and hopefully you can give me some credit as well...

Comment: Please move the "edit part of the question" into an answer and accept it. That way, it can serve as a reference to other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: solved it. I had added previously the following line of code after

[sender setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

```
 [sender addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cause of exception was i added colon (:) twice after @selector(buttonClicked2) whereas i need only one colon.
```

I hope this question serves as reference to other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to iOS but:

1. Set a property that has the button state, or extend the button (some people don't recommend)
2. When it changes state, change the color and the label.

Wouldn't that work. Probably other users have better solutions.

Cheers.

Comment: I am able to change the label that is from follow to unfollow and vice versa. But after label changes, I need to perform the coreesponding action again on button click -ie- if state changes from follow to unfollow and if i click the button with label as unfollow, it should perform the unfollow action again... in my case its throwing exception.